# Is a Hostname A Entry necessary?

Tags: hostname

When I log into WHM, I get this message:

> The server was unable to lookup an an A entry for its hostname (server226.taxi.com). This is generally because the entry was never added. However this could also be the result of your nameserver(s) being down. If you would like to attempt to automatically add the entry, click here.

If I click "here" it does nothing and I still get the message. I'm not hosting websites for other people, just internal projects on our server. Does not having an A Hostname Record affect SEO or anything like that or is this just a convenience when setting up nameservers or something like that?

Comment: Questions concerning the use of shared web hosting in a development environment are off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it wants to have a hostname because in some areas of the control panel it refers to the hostname instead of the IP address. When you click "here" it will have you set up an A record in WHM; but if you DNS is hosted elsewhere this doesn't do anything.

Generally speaking you should have an A record for the server, but I think functionally each service should work without any problems even if an A record is not set up. As long are you are comfortable setting everything up manually you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to a variety of misconfigurations, not necessarily a missing A record (which isn't exactly necessary if you have a CNAME record pointing to an A record, or a AAAA record...). If everything is working as you expect it to, then don't worry about this. If things aren't working correctly, time to mess with the DNS.

Search engines generally see the same site you do, so if it's coming up correctly, chances are SEO will be correct too.